# Change the Internal Drive as a removal drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a external USB HDD which is being displayed as one of the internal drives of my computer. It's not coming as removable disk. How to change this?

Comment: Are you sure it's really USB, and not eSATA? eSATA is the "external" version of SATA. As a result, every OS has challenges in figuring out whether a given SATA drive is internal.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour as it's a hard disk, as opposed to flash based memory.

To remove safely, use the icon in the system tray, right-click and choose the disk there. This will spin the hard drive down for safe removal.